# Figure or Div, which should I use?

Tags: seo, html, html5, technical-seo

I'm designing a news site. I use thumbnails of news on the homepage. Should I use the div or figure tag for them?

Sample figure,

```
<a href="/news_url">
<figure>
  <img src="news.jpg" alt="news">
  <figcaption>News headline</figcaption>
</figure></a>
```

Sample div,

```
<a href="/news_url">
<div>
  <img src="news.jpg" alt="news">
</div>
  <span>News headline</span>
</a>
```

Does it make any difference in terms of SEO?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact, if you use either of them, you will not encounter any SEO problems, but it would be better to use the `<figcaption>` HTML5 tag for better SEO. Because Google bots recognize these tags and understand why you are typing that text. If you use span, Google bots will only see it as a text.

So my answer is:

```
<a href="/news_url">
<figure>
  <img src="news.jpg" alt="news">
  <figcaption>News headline</figcaption>
</figure></a>
```

Comment: Thanks dude,  I actually thought the same as you, but I was a little confused when I saw that many news sites use divs.

Comment: @awaken I think that since news sites did not do this at first, they continue with the same usage.